# What Do I Do When I don't know the Data Type I'll Need?

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm trying to make my own library with data structures and algorithms. The problem is that I don't know what type to use for the data variable. Some day I may need to use this for holding integers, another for strings. Any idea what to do?

Example:

```
typedef struct tree{
    int data;
    struct tree *left;
    struct tree *right;
}tree;
```

But if I want to use strings, should I change the data type manually or there is a way to declarer data in other way?

Comment: i think your question lacks detailed description. give an example of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: You could try using `void *`. But you should share more details to your situation.

Comment: Perhaps the library function `qsort` can serve as inspiration. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/

Comment: Go to c++ and implement that with templates

Comment: `malloc` is used when creating all sorts of data structures ;) And it returns a `void *`.

Comment: Thank you Arjun Shankar and Aliou

Comment: Yup. `void *` is the way to do this in C.

Comment: Do it like the stdclib does, i.e. using the generic `void*` pointer, see the examples of [qsort](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) and [bsearch](http://linux.die.net/man/3/bsearch). For any action you do you will always have to provide some function pointer to a function which can deal with the data you pass to it.

Comment: Hold on OP, let me finish my ice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that what I say may be just nonsense, but here's what I think: What about the unions?

```
typedef struct tree{
    union {
        int i;
        char * c;
    } data;
    struct tree *left;
    struct tree *right;
}tree;
```

Isn't this thing above what you more or less want to have? A block of memory, either to be used as an `int` or a `char *`. Let me briefly explain what a `union` is: When a `union` variable gets created, a memory location that is as large as the largest one inside. Since all the sub-variables inside the union will be using the same memory location, they will be overwriting each other.

For example, if I were to create a `tree` out of the thing above directly, like this:

```
tree asd;
```

I could use the `data` inside to store an integer with the following manner:

```
asd.data.i = 123;
```

And then I could very well create a branch on the left, store a string inside:

```
asd.left = malloc( sizeof asd );
asd.left->data.c = malloc( 10 );
memcpy( asd.left->data.c, "kek", 4 );
```

If you don't like the `data` in between, you can omit that! But first, you have to omit it from the declaration as well.

```
typedef struct tree{
    union {
        int i;
        char * c;
    };          // <-- removed the data
    struct tree *left;
    struct tree *right;
}tree;
```

Then you can access both `i` and `c` without writing `data.` behind.

I hope that all this was not nonsense and actually becomes useful, heh.

Comment: It's a decent compromise, but it's just masking poor planning for API/interface design. It also can be very wasteful if it's the union of a single character, or a massive array of structs.

Comment: @Dogbert Array of structures will only have the size of a pointer, not any more than a `char *` or any other pointer... But yeah, if you have both a `double` and a `char` inside the union, then you'll be wasting some space.

Comment: I disagree. You can actually allocate a complete array within a struct, which is allocated automatically on the stack. A more efficient way would be a pointer-to-struct which is initialized dynamically on the heap, but it's still possible. Also, not all pointers are the same size (ie: function pointers vs primitive data type pointers).

Comment: @Dogbert Oh well, yeah... I had thought that it would just be a pointer to the allocated memory for an array of structures. You could do that, but you shouldn't do that really. You wouldn't even be able to do that if you were to fix yourself to `void *`. Best way to use this construction I've offered would be to include only types that are less than or equal to 4 bytes inside the union, maybe 8. For anything larger, rather a pointer to that type should be included, and enough much memory should be allocated to use it as a variable of that type.

Comment: I made a different struct for each type(string/char;int;float/double) But thank you this answer give me the idea.

Comment: @user3395407 Glad it helped in a way. That was the first thing came to my mind, but I thought that you just strictly wanted all inside one structure.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just changing the internal guts of your own program, you could just define your own data type via `typedef`.

```
typedef int myDataType;
typedef struct tree{
    myDataType data;
    struct tree *left;
    struct tree *right;
} tree;
```

You really need to decide in advance what the data type is though (integral, floating point, string), or you'll have to do a decent amount of re-writing later on. Using the extra typedef though, will save you time and help you track down all places where the data is directly manipulated or read.

Also, if you just cast the structure to `(void*)`, you can have generic functions that accept `(void*)` as an argument, then recast the argument in the function body.

```
int myFunction(void* input) {
  tree* data;
  if (!input) {
    return (-1);
  }
  data = (tree*)input;
  ...
  return 0;
}

int main(void) {
  tree myTree;
  myFunction((void*)&myTree);
  ...
  return 0;
}
```